# Javascript variable value in functions won't pass to other functions

Tags: javascript, function

I'm a student currently learning web development right now, and I'm working on building a quiz with HTML, CSS, and Javascript. I've run into a problem that I can't seem to fix. I've attached my code below:

```
let username;
let timeleft;
let currentQuestion = 0;
let score = 0;
let cheat = 0;
let questions = [
   {
    "question": "What is the capital of Norway?",
    "a": "Oslo",
    "b": "Tromsø",
    "c": "Bergen",
    "d": "Stavanger",
    "image":"quizimages/norway.png",
    "answer": "a"
   },
   {
    "question": "What is the capital of the Dominican Republic?",
    "a": "Santiago",
    "b": "La Vega",
    "c": "Santo Domingo",
    "d": "San Francisco de Macorís",
    "image":"quizimages/dominicanRepublic.png",
    "answer": "c"
   },
   {
    "question": "What is the capital of Iraq?",
    "a": "Mosul",
    "b": "Basra",
    "c": "Baghdad",
    "d": "Kirkuk",
    "image":"quizimages/iraq.png",
    "answer": "c"
   },
   {
    "question": "What is the capital of Montenegro?",
    "a": "Herceg Novi",
    "b": "Podgorica",
    "c": "Nikšić",
    "d": "Pljevlja",
    "image":"quizimages/montenegro.png",
    "answer": "b"
   },
   {
    "question": "What is the capital of Cuba?",
    "a": "Holguín",
    "b": "Guantánamo",
    "c": "Santiago de Cuba",
    "d": "Havana",
    "image":"quizimages/cuba.png",
    "answer": "d"
   },
   {
    "question": "What is the capital of East Timor?",
    "a": "Dili",
    "b": "Maubara",
    "c": "Likisá",
    "d": "Suai",
    "image":"quizimages/eastTimor.png",
    "answer": "a"
   },
   {
    "question": "What is the capital of Madagascar?",
    "a": "Fianarantsoa",
    "b": "Antsirabe",
    "c": "Toamasina",
    "d": "Antananarivo",
    "image":"quizimages/madagascar.png",
    "answer": "d"
   },
   {
    "question": "What is the capital of Kenya?",
    "a": "Mombasa",
    "b": "Nakuru",
    "c": "Eldoret",
    "d": "Nairobi",
    "image":"quizimages/kenya.png",
    "answer": "d"
   },
   {
    "question": "What is the capital of Liechtenstein?",
    "a": "Schellenberg",
    "b": "Vaduz",
    "c": "Planken",
    "d": "Schaan",
    "image":"quizimages/liechtenstein.png",
    "answer": "b"
   },
   {
    "question": "What is the capital of Afghanistan?",
    "a": "Mazari Sharif",
    "b": "Kandahar",
    "c": "Kabul",
    "d": "Jalalabad",
    "image":"quizimages/afghanistan.png",
    "answer": "c"
   },
 ];
 
// server worker
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js');
}


 
 function loadQuestion() {
    // close light box for first question
        if (currentQuestion == 0) {
            closeLightBox();
        }   
   
    // timer
    let downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + " seconds remaining";
    timeleft -= 1;
    if(timeleft <= 0){
      clearInterval(downloadTimer);
      document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Finished";
      window.location.replace("thanks.html");
      }
    }, 1000);
   
    // play music
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event => {
    const audio = document.querySelector("audio");
    audio.loop = true;
    audio.volume = 0.2;
    audio.play();
    });

   
    // prompt user for name and set timer
    if (username == null) {
      username = prompt("What is your name?")
      timeleft = prompt("Welcome, " + username + ". Please set your timer to how much time you want for the quiz (in seconds):");
    } // if 
      
        // load the image
        let img = document. getElementById("image");
        img.src = questions [currentQuestion].image;
        img.style.maxWidth = "80%";
     
     
        // load the question and answers
        document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = questions[currentQuestion].question;
        document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "A. " + questions[currentQuestion].a;
        document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = "B. " + questions[currentQuestion].b;  
        document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = "C. " + questions[currentQuestion].c;
        document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = "D. " + questions[currentQuestion].d;
        
 } // loadQuestion
    
 
 function markIt(ans) {
     
        let message = "";
        
        if (ans == questions[currentQuestion].answer) {
            
            // Add 1 to score
            score++;
            
            // display score
            document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score + " / " + questions.length;
            
            // output message to user when answer is correct
            message = "Correct!!!! Your current score is " + score + " / " + (currentQuestion + 1) + ", or " + Math.round(score / (currentQuestion + 1) * 100) + "%"; 
            document.getElementById("message").style.backgroundColor = "green";
            document.getElementById("message").style.color = "white";
            
        } else {
            
            // output message to user when answer is incorrect
            message = "Incorrect :( Your current score is " + score + " / " + (currentQuestion + 1) + ", or " + Math.round(score / (currentQuestion + 1) * 100) + "%";
            document.getElementById("message").style.backgroundColor = "red";
            document.getElementById("message").style.color = "white";
            
        } // end of if/else
        
        //show the lightbox
        document.getElementById("lightbox").style.display = "block"; // display: block; might need to be changed later
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = message;
        
        // move to the next question
        currentQuestion++;
        if (currentQuestion < questions.length) {
            loadQuestion();
        } else {
            window.location.replace("thanks.html");
        }
        
 }  // markIt 
 

 function GiveMeTheAnswer(){
    let message = "";
        score++;
    cheat++;
        message = "...Imagine being lazy and not trying to answer the question yourself :( Oh well, your current score is " + score + " / " + (currentQuestion + 1) + ", or " + Math.round(score / (currentQuestion + 1) * 100) + "%"; 
        document.getElementById("message").style.backgroundColor = "orange";
        document.getElementById("message").style.color = "white";
        document.getElementById("lightbox").style.display = "block"; // display: block; might need to be changed later
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = message;
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score + " / " + questions.length;
    currentQuestion++;
    if (currentQuestion < questions.length) {
        loadQuestion();
    } else {
        window.location.replace("thanks.html");
    }
} // GiveMeTheAnswer


 function closeLightBox(){
     document.getElementById("lightbox").style.display = "none";
 } // closeLightBox


function thanks(){
  let message = "";
  else if(score == 10) {
    message = "Congratulations! You got a perfect score!";
  } 
  else if (score < 10 && score > 8) {
    message = "Nice, you did pretty well :D";
  } 
  else if (score < 8 && score > 6){
    message = "Well... at least you passed.";
  }
  else if (score < 6 && score > 3) {
    message = "Hmmm... you should probably practice and try again."
  } else if (score < 3) {
    message = "That's just unfortunate."
  }
  
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = message;
  
  document.getElementById("message").style.backgroundColor = "cyan";
}
```

So essentially, I'm trying to get the score variable stored in markIt() or GiveMeTheAnswer() so I can make a customized message in my thanks() method. However, scope appears to limit it, so whenever I try to access the "score" variable, it ends up being 0 (because of its initialization as a global variable up on the top). How could I fix this? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: That's odd, I can't find any reason why scope should be a problem. Are you sure that the score remains `0`?

Comment: Also to note, your `thanks()` function misses the scores 3, 6, and 8, you should change your `>`'s to `>=`.

Comment: Sorry, I may not have been clear enough. When my thanks() function tries to access score, it's always 0. Originally (before I posted) I actually had a test if statement. if (score == 0), and it would always be 0. Now that it's removed, running it always returns "That's just unfortunate," the case for score < 3.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the missing scores, I'll fix that

Comment: Also there is still an extra `else` before your `if` statement

Comment: `score` is only declared once at global scale so scope shouldn't be a problem... I think you might be resetting the score too early or something, could you post all of your code, particularly the part were `thanks` is actually called?

Comment: That is all my javascript code. I realized my error, though: thanks() is being used on a different html page as my other functions. So when I move to the other html page, the variables are resetting. Is there anyway to overcome this?

Comment: `localStorage` maybe? I've never done anything like that before..., Also how necessary is it to open a new page?

Comment: I figured it out... localStorage was the way to go! Thank you so much, for helping me realize that scope wasn't my problem :)